# OpenCV VideoCapture: GStreamer not working

Tags: python, opencv, spyder, gstreamer

I'm trying to use cv2.VideoCapture in Spyder 5.3.2 to read frames from an AVI using an environment created by Anaconda and keep getting the following errors:

> [ WARN:0@0.641] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin

> [ WARN:0@0.641] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2402) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin0 reported: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.

> [ WARN:0@0.641] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline

> [ WARN:0@0.641] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

> [ WARN:0@1.010] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2180) cv::CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot link elements

> [ERROR:0@1.030] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (597) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

> OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): roi_cropped_output.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

> [ WARN:0@1.030] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2180) cv::CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot link elements

> [ERROR:0@1.031] global C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (597) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

> OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\Windows\Temp\abs_0aavye6esb\croots\recipe\opencv-suite_1659973594283\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): binarized_output.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

I looked at a number of similar posts and made sure to install spyder within the anaconda environment and reinstalling opencv and ffmpeg pacakges using conda-forge but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem

helped to install Gstreamer via brew and then change condo virtual env.

probably first step is unnecessary

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34402230)